# Using karate.call along with conditional logic

Tags: karate

I have a test.feature which takes a json as argument.
In scenariosFile.feature, I need to write a logic like below

if (response_size < 100 ) -> call test.feature with argumentJson as argument.

I tried doing it in multiple ways, but it is not calling test.feature, not sure where I am going wrong.

```
* def argumentJson = {"id:"1234", "name":"david"}
* response_size = 99
```

`* if (response_size < 100) karate.call(classpath:/tests/reusable/test.feature,argumentJson)`

`* eval if (response_size < 100) karate.call(classpath:/tests/reusable/test.feature,argumentJson)`

`* def result = (response_size < 100) ?  karate.call(classpath:/tests/reusable/test.feature,argumentJson) : {}`